# Probability of a event conditioned to its distribution

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I have a sets of tweets each of which have a time-stamp. The time stamp shows when the tweet is created. Also every tweet is labeled. Assume that the distribution of time stamps is Gaussian and I computed every classes distribution. Now how can I compute the probability that each tweet belongs to each class conditioned to that classes distribution?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what these classes are? Are they related to labels? Are the labels and classes dependent on time-stamps, or vice-versa? An example data would help.

Comment: @A.G. classes are location which is correspond to a tweet which are the same as the labels, as a simple example a tweet which is originated at New York is labeled 1 and a one which is originated at Los Angles is labeled 0. Are they Dependant? The paper which I'm reviewing says so which makes sense but I want to compute the conditional probability which is something they didn't do, I would try to add some more information to the original question, thank you for your comment